# Using a second passport strategy using the same User model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I started a node project some time ago using Node, Express, MongoDB and Passport using passport-local-mongoose for user auth using sessions, and my user model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  //etc

});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Now i want to create a react native app for the same webapp, so I want to use the same DB of users.

My questions is: can I use something like passport-jwt alongside the current user model and auth strategy that I have on the website? Or do you guys recommend me to re-create the complete project using jsonwebtokens for auth only and then trying to import the current users DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a new strategy using same db. create a passport.js file and initiate the strategy type you want to use for that user. From there you can call the same model and check the auth of that user from the same db. You also need to write a comparePassowrd function in model. So you can compare your password for login and session will be maintain for web frontend

```
    passport.use('user',new LocalStrategy({    
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'

    }, function (username, password, done) {

        Collection.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {

            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {"user not found"});
            }        
            user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!isMatch) {
                    return done(null, false,  {"wrong password"});
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }
));
```

Add isAuthenticated and isAuthorized Functions in passport.js

```
passport.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {  
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
}
res.status(401);
return next({"user not authenticated"});
};
passport.isAuthorized = (userType) => {   
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.user.userType == userType) {       
            return next();
        }
        res.status(403);
        return next({"user not authorized"});
    };
};
```

Here userType is for different level of users for example: admin/ moderator etc

Now in route just call the auth function before moving to the actual function

```
app.post('/apiRoute',passport.isAuthenticated, passport.isAuthorized('ADMIN'),controllerFile.actualFunction;
```